# Преобразование DTO в GET-запрос

Tags: java, get, dto

Всем привет.

Мне необходимо преобразовать dto в набор параметров GET-строки.

Вот, к примеру, у меня DTO (геттеры-сеттеры опустил):

```
public class ProductDto extends AbstractDto {

    private String name;
    private Double proteins;
    private Double fats;
    private Double carbohydrates;
    private Integer calories;
    private Long productType;
 }
```

Мне нужно преобразовать их в такой запрос:

```
?name=null&proteins=null&fats=null&calories=null&productType=1000121
```

(к примеру).

Как это сделать при помощи библиотек того же `Spring` или, скажем, `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: А где вы это используете, если не секрет.

Comment: Это коммерческая тайна, конечно.

Comment: я к тому, что если имеете дело с урл, то может вам поможе что-то вроде UriComponentsBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, за неимением под рукой таких библиотек, я написал в итоге метод, который создаёт такую строку, через рефлексию:

```
public String generateRequestParams(D dto) {
        final Boolean[] first = {true};
        AtomicReference<String> request = new AtomicReference<>("");
        Arrays.asList(dto.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).forEach(field -> {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String param = "";
            try {
                param = String.valueOf(field.get(dto));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(param, "null")) {
                if (first[0]) {
                    first[0] = false;
                    request.set(request + "?" + field.getName() + "=" + param);
                } else {
                    request.set(request + "&" + field.getName() + "=" + param);
                }
            }
            field.setAccessible(false);
        });
        return String.valueOf(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно обойтись и без каких либо библиотек - просто реализовать метод, который будет конвертировать объект в нужную строку.

Comment: Да, можно и так, но уже много лет подход, когда разработчик пишет всю логику сам, считается неправильным. Это называется низкоуровневое программирование, оно отнимает много времени и понижает производительность разработчика. Этот подход я рассматривал, но отложил на крайний случай.

Comment: Ну если использовать какую либо библиотеку то для этой цели она, скорее всего, будет инкапсулировать подобный метод на таком же уровне. Просто Вы об этом знать не будете;)